# Getting correct linefeeds in emails generated from linux

Tags: email, log-files, scripting, sed, formatting

I have a script that emails certain linux log entries to me, and I read the email in MS Outlook.

The problem is that all the lines run together with no linefeeds between the lines.

To address this I inserted **sed "s/$/\n/"** before the mail command, but *that gives me 2 linefeeds between each line in the email*!

What is the proper way to get a single linefeed between each line (using sed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check to make sure your Outlook isn't helpfully removing line breaks for you (ie the problem isn't Linux, it's Outlook).  By default I think it does.  It should be telling you this at the top of the view panel.

Comment: Indeed, this is it (I should learn to read better).  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Any idea why Outlook thinks these are "Extra" line breaks?  It removes ALL OF THEM!

Comment: It is trying to helpfully line-wrap so that lines that were made in an older mail client where formatting was done explicitly and not through indirect markup tags take advantage of your million-character-wide message view pane.

Answer (score 5):

If you add 2 spaces to the beginning of each line, Outlook will not remove the linefeeds.

```
sed "s/^/  /"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need:

```
sed 's/$/\r/g'
```

Comment: No, I tried \r, \r\n - all with the same results