# How does Outlook identify "Extra Line Breaks"

Tags: linux, email, scripting, outlook

I am writing a script that emails the output to me, and I read it in Outlook.  For some reason Outlook removes **all the line breaks** in the message, and gives me a little notice that it has removed the *extra line breaks from the message*

How can I fix my message so that Outlook doesn't remove  the line breaks?

- Outlook displays other messages fine (with correct line breaks)
- I have tried all these things with sed - s/$/\r/  s/$/\n/  s/\r\n/\n/  s/\n\r/\n/  s/$/^M/  - with no luck

What does Outlook expect at the end of a line?

Comment: I'm thinking.. shouldn't programming questions be posted in stackoverflow instead?

Comment: I put it here because I thought it would be more applicable to sysadmins than programmers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about what it's looking for, but how about configuring Outlook to not remove them?

Tools -> Options -> Preferences Tab -> click E-mail Options button -> uncheck the box

Another option (albeit not ideal and maybe not even the case for your msgs):

1. Open Outlook.
2. Open the item.
3. Click Format.
4. Click to clear the Unwrap Text check mark.

And [**here's a post**](http://www.masternewmedia.org/newsletter_publishing/newsletter_formatting/remove_line_breaks_issue_Microsoft_Outlook_2003_when_publishing_text_newsletters_20051217.htm) that says that a hack you can use would be to add 2 empty characters to the beginning of each line of text in order to make Outlook not remove the breaks.

Additionally see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638608/1498669) for a better layout, add at least 3 spaces at the end of every line (incl. empty lines).

Comment: He's asking how Outlook parses the mails, not how he can shut off the behaviour in Outlook.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  But frequently other suggestions end up working better than the requested functionality.  I also posted a hack more toward what he was asking.

Comment: Dude.  The problem is "Outlook is misbehaving", not "the message is broken".  Fix the Outlook problem.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/26004/getting-correct-linefeeds-in-emails-generated-from-linux

Comment: Ok - you edited and it looks a bit more helpful now, I'm taking my -1 back

Comment: That hack of adding 2 spaces to the beginning of each line works great!  I just did sed "s/^/  /" before the mail command.

Comment: I think that's right, I had a similar problem with Pegasus mail.  Make sure still generate line breaks because there is a maximum line length at which your line will just be truncated.

Comment: @pauska: BTW - Thanks for explaining the downvote earlier!  Kinda bugs me when people don't do that...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638608/1498669 and add at least 3 spaces at the end - better for layout :)